# Python3: How to stop/kill thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

My code runs N number of threads. I want to stop specific threads on some condition but the remaining threads should continue running. I am doing some operation once each thread finishes its job. Is there a way to stop running thread in Python 3.

My current code is implemented in Python2 which does this by "_Thread__stop()". Is there any identical thing in Python3?

Comment: You realize [there is *no* safe way to kill a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/323972/364696), even when some misguided APIs (like WinAPI) allow it, right? Among the most basic issues, if it holds a lock (not just one of your locks, it could be some implicit lock in a library or allocator you never see), that lock is held forever, and any other thread that needs it is blocked, forever.

Answer (score 0):

The practice is to "signal" the thread that it is time to finish and then the thread needs to exit. This is not killing like you kill a process but a regular state machine behavior of your thread function.

For example, suppose your thread is lopping. You should insert an if statement inside the loop that instructing the thread function to **break or return** `if stop is True`. The `stop` variable should be a shared variable with the main thread (or the thread who need to stop out thread) that will change it to `True`. usually after this, the stopper thread will want to wait for the thread completion by `join()`

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad habit to kill a thread, better is to create a "flag" which will tell you when your thread made its work done.
Consider the following example:

```
import threading
import random

class CheckSomething(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, variable):
        super(CheckSomething, self).__init__()
        self.start_flag = threading.Event()
        self.variable = variable

    def check_position(self, variable):
        x = random.randint(100)
        if variable == x:
            self.stop_checking()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.check_position(self.variable) 

    def stop_checking():
        self.start_flag.set()

    def stopped():
        return self.start_flag.is_set()
```

The set() method of Event() set its status to True. More you can read in docs: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html

So you need to call stop_checking() when you meet a condition where you want exit.